# How can I add rich text to a text area

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

Is there a way to set part of the text of the textarea with style. For example if i have a text area with this value:

> `Hi, how are you`

I'd want this :

> hi how are **you**

Setting the words that I want in bold and not all the values wrote in the text area. I would like do it with jQuery maybe a plugin or something.

My text area:

```
<textarea id="txtMessageFields" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
```

Comment: I recommend a NO-jQuery solution mentioned over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37758563/1920145

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a WYSIWYG HTML editor for this purpose, like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

For example, with CKEditor's jQuery interface this is as easy as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document.ready(function () {
         $('#txtMessageFields').ckeditor();
     });
</script>
```

from [CKEditor jQuery Adapter Guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter)

Take a look at the configuration options to only enable the functionalities you need.

Comment: And for all the fanciness of those editors, they boil down to taking a block element and settings its "contentEditable" attribute to true, enabling realtime changes to the block's contents.

Comment: @Marc This is only one option, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel. Looks a bit overkill for only using **Bold**, but it is unclear to me whether the OP only needs this functionality.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like you're using duplicate `id`s there, with `#txtMessageFields`. That's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try [THIS](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/2007-09-11-1/) its what you want. See the demo [here](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html)

Comment: Freak and if i don't want to show the panel a setting bold in js part of the text with that pluing i can do it?

Comment: You mean that you want to hide the buttons on top?

Comment: Freak yeap i only need to modify the text in the code no fby the user

Comment: check @Álvaro G. Vicario's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `<textarea>` element can only hold plain text:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea

As far as I know, all JavaScript WYSIWYG editors use a regular DOM node (an iframe or a div) and use regular HTML/CSS to get visual styles. You could write some code to dynamically replace your textarea but I assume it's a form field in the first place because it needs to be editable. If so, I suggest you pick a third-party editor. Here's quite a comprehensive list:

- http://geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/WebEditors

Answer (score 1):

As wrote bazmegakapa, you must use a WYSIWYG editor. From my experience, the best is TinyMCE, which includes a special package if you use jQuery ([TinyMCE jQuery package](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download/download.php)).